# p-calendar item doesn't modify your width

Tags: angular, css, primeng

I use [primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) to create the calendar.

I need to modify the width about input p-calendar item . Suppose to have this code:

```
 <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dataCalendar" [showIcon]="true" inputStyleClass="modifywidth" ></p-calendar>
```

the class modifywidth is this:

```
.modifywidth{
width: 100%;
}
```

But I don't see the new input p-calendar width. The modifywidth class is the in component:

```
 <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ng-tns-c6-0 modifywidth ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-klass="modifywidth" ng-reflect-ng-class="ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-stat" placeholder="">
```

Anyone can help me?